# When trying to create an S3 bucket with the following config, keep on running into this error: Template validation error

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

```
BucketUser:
    Type: AWS::IAM::User 
    Properties:
      PolicyName: InTheBucket  
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
          - s3:GetObject
          - s3:PutObject
          - s3:PutBucketCORS
          - s3:PutObjectAcl
          Resource: arn:aws:s3:::flask-Bucket

BucketKey:
    Type: AWS::IAM::AccessKey
    Properties:
      Username:
        !Ref BucketUser

Outputs:
  WebsiteURL:
    Value: !GetAtt S3Bucket
    Export:
      Name: S3Bucket
  BucketKey:
    Value: !Ref BucketKey
    Export:
      Name: BucketKey
  SecretAccessKey:
    Value: !GetAtt BucketKey.SecretAccessKey
    Export:
      Name: SecretAccessKey
```

```
Error name :  Template error: if specifying one argument to Fn::GetAtt,   
that argument must be a non-empty string in format <LogicalId>.<Attribute>.
```

I have been referencing [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-iam.html#scenario-iam-policy).

Comment: The error refers to `Value: !GetAtt S3Bucket`, where `S3Bucket` is not in the format `<LogicalId>.<Attribute>`.  You *might* be looking for either `S3Bucket.WebsiteURL` or `S3Bucket.DomainName`.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [return values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html#aws-properties-bucket-ref) for `AWS::S3::Bucket`

For the `WebsiteURL` output, try:

```
WebsiteURL:
  Value: !GetAtt S3Bucket.WebsiteURL
  Export:
    Name: S3Bucket
```